# Shell Script for file transfer

Tags: shell

There are files in my source directory where files are uploaded by each user and hence they would be created under each user directory.
Ex: /uploads/Naveen/file1
/uploads/Ram/file1
/uploads/....

I need a shell script to check these files that are older than 60 days and copy them to destination directory and remove them from the source directory.They need to be transferred along with the user directory i.e /destination_directory/Naveen/file1 and /destination_directory/Ram/file1 and so on.

It would be really helpful if any solution is provided for this request.

Comment: Which shell language are you using?

Comment: In general, a good Stack Overflow question asks about a problem you encountered _when writing a program yourself_, instead of asking us to write a program for you.

Comment: I have used this program..but it is not working as the structure is not being maintained in destination path after the files are transferred.
#!/bin/bash
SourceDir=/path
RemoteDir=/path
find $SourceDir -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f -exec mv "{}" $RemoteDir \;

Answer (score 0):

To move all **files** in /sourcedirectory and all **subfolders** under source directory use:

```
find /sourcedirectory -mtime +60 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

To move only **files** in in /sourcedirectory use -maxdepth 1 flag:

```
find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +60 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am aware of those commands.But thing is the structure of the source directory has to be reflected in the destination directory as well.The files older than x days under "/sourcedir/subfolder1" should be transferred with the structure "/destinationdir/subfolder1" and similarly files older than x days under "/sourcedir/subfolder2" as "/destinationdir/subfolder2".The files under each subfolder should not get mixed with other subfolder in the destination path.I hope u get it.